# Can I map same url-pattern to two local-path in WebLogic?

Tags: weblogic, virtual-directory

I want to map something as below, is it possible?

```
<wls:virtual-directory-mapping>
    <wls:local-path>D:/OTJ/upload</wls:local-path>
    <wls:url-pattern>/*</wls:url-pattern>
</wls:virtual-directory-mapping>
<wls:virtual-directory-mapping>
    <wls:local-path>D:/OTK/upload</wls:local-path>
    <wls:url-pattern>/*</wls:url-pattern>
</wls:virtual-directory-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

never tried but I dont think you can, Weblogic don't know where to look for resources in that case (or probably will choose only one of the two).
What's the wanted behavior?